# ReportParameterValueNotSetException in SSRS subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I am not getting this error locally in VS 2005
or when running the report through the preview

but during subscription I start getting

ReportParameterValueNotSetException
even though all my parameters especially the one it's complaining about is set

this has started happening all of a sudden and has been working great before.

Any ideas why this might have happened

Answer (score 0):

You could try deploying the report with a different name and see if subscriptions for it have the same problem. If it does not, then blame cosmic rays.  It happens. In that case, delete the old report entirely from the server and then you should be able to deploy with the original name again.

If it continues to happen, then I'd start looking at what's different between running it live and running it through a subscription. Usually it's permissions related. Or perhaps the time of day the subscription fires off vs the time of day you test it live.

Answer (score 0):

Is the parameter value used for the subscription hard coded, or is it based on another query?

If the latter
 - does the query used for this param gen purpose work?
 - does it return the correct datatype/expected data?
 - does it work at the time you are running the report (database is online, has permissions set correctly)?